# how to deploy web project on tomcat which has link with two java projects in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6

i have developed one web project which has liked with tow java projects. when i want to deploy my application in tomcat server, i have to upload war file. im in a confusion that how to create that war file( how to include java projects into the war file). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you can add a tomcat instance within eclipse.
whether you have your tomcat inside or out of eclipse, you can deploy all the necessary projects on it

Comment: The linked projects will need to be deployed as jar files

Comment: out of eclipse..Thanks for ur reply

Comment: OK i ll try with deploying jar files..Thanks for ur reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pack the requested projects as jar files in WEB_INF/lib directory in your war. When You export the project from the Eclipse, dependent projects should be added there automatically.

Comment: when i start tomcat within eclipse my application is working fine. But when i start tomcat server through command prompt it is not displaying properly.. what may be d reason?

Comment: What is a problem? When you create a war (Export --> WAR file) does it contains dependent projects as jars?

Comment: yes..in WEB-INF/lib folder,jars are der.. but starting server through cmd prompt it is not working..:(

Comment: before i started my application through Eclipse,that it was working fine.

Comment: it is showing 404 exception while fetching files through ajax cmnctn(it shd fetch n display those files in web page)..

Comment: can u please tell me wat to do??

Comment: Check if war is contained in *<tomcat_home>/webapps* directory. If you unpack war files, check if *<tomcat_home>/webapps/<your_app_name>* directory exists and has proper structure.